# Cannot read property 'download' of undefined $cordovaFileTransfer in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, file-transfer, ngcordova

I want to use $cordovaFileTransfer in my app to dowload  image data, but after trying to implement the code, this error is showing up:

> Cannot read property 'download' of undefined

here is my code:

```
var url = "blablabla.com/img.png";
var targetPath = "img/"+ imgpaths;
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};

    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
      .then(function(result) {
        // Success!
        console.log('Download Success' + targetPath);
      }, function(err) {
        // Error
      }, function (progress) {
        $timeout(function () {
          var downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
          console.log('Progress : '+downloadProgress);
        });

  });
```

anybody can help me?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue? My problem is not like this but It would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this issues list:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

For example have you wrapped the call to `$cordovaFileTransfer.download()` inside `deviceready` handler or better inside `$ionicPlatform.ready()` ?